# How do I check for something in Entity Framework that I know doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method that I want to do different things based on database state.

One of the last things my method does is save something to the database. Every time this method is run, it works as expected/the value gets changed - other than the first time.

For a complicated reason, I can't use a seed method here, but, what is the correct way of doing this?

adding

```
      if (db.Settings.First(x=>x.name=="DBState").Value == "1")
            return false;
```

causes a sequence doesn't exist error, and the following

```
      if (db.Settings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.name=="DBState").Value == "1")
            return false;
```

it causes following exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: If one/any of these answers were right for you, please mark it as such for the benefit of future searchers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use `Any()` to get a boolean result ?

```
return db.Settings.Any(x => x.name == "DBState" && x.Value == "1");
```

Comment: I think the `FirstOrDefault` will be slightly faster, because it'll stop searching after the first occurrence had been found. The `Any` method will always go through the whole list if the DBState exists but the `Value != "1"`

Comment: @Pieter  In an `IQueryable` world, Sql is generated. No question of list (that's not linq to objects)...  So this one will probably be faster (no noticeable difference, I would say), as the query will retrieve a boolean, not a complete setting, which is not needed.
Another point : in fact, the two queries don't do exactly the same. One takes the first (depending on what order? Mystery...) setting with name "DbState". This query checks if there's at least one setting with name "DbState" and Value == "1".

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the value of a null, hence the exception.

Try

```
var myObj = db.Settings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.name=="DBState");

if(myObj != null){
 // do stuff here safely
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the last option and add a null check to it:

```
var setting = db.Settings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.name=="DBState");
if (setting != null && setting.Value == "1")
        return false;
```